# Button Drag and Drop in JavaFX

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx-2

I am trying to develop an application where user is able to drag a buttons from a pallet and drop it to a canvas to create workflows. Once user dropped a button to the canvas, he should be able to double click on the button to open a form to update details and save it.

The help I need is on implementing drag and drop part. Can anyone help me pls

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**Here is how I have implemented drag and drop button and  double click event**

```
double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
double orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;
int i = 1;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        Label label = new Label();

        Button button = new Button("Hello");
        button.setOnMousePressed(buttonMousePressedEventHandler);
        button.setOnMouseDragged(buttonOnMouseDraggedEventHandler);
        button.setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);

        button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
                    if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        label.setText("Double Click Fire... " + i);
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        HBox box = new HBox();
        box.setSpacing(15);
        box.getChildren().addAll(button);

        VBox box2 = new VBox();
        box2.setSpacing(50);
        box2.getChildren().addAll(label, box);

        root.setCenter(box2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

EventHandler<MouseEvent> buttonMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
        orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
        orgTranslateX = ((Button) (t.getSource())).getTranslateX();
        orgTranslateY = ((Button) (t.getSource())).getTranslateY();

        ((Button) (t.getSource())).toFront();
    }
};

EventHandler<MouseEvent> buttonOnMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
        double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
        double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
        double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;

        ((Button) (t.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
        ((Button) (t.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keyur, I will try this and see